# Swift 3: retrieving text from a UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to retrieve text from the `UITextField` in custom cell and assign the value to `self.email` variable in my view controller. When I make a breakpoint in `textFieldDidEndEditing` function, I can see that the value of the `textField` is assigned to `self.email` as expected, but the variable `self.email` is nil in `@IBAction doneButtonDidPress` function.

**Question:** Why the value of `self.email` is changed to `nil`?

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let text = textField.text {
        self.email = text
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)) as! AboutCell
    cell.textView?.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
}
}
```

I'm using `UITableViewController`, that's how I create cells:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profilePhotoCell")! as! ProfilePhotoCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell")! as! TextFieldCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Email"
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "aboutCell")! as! AboutCell
        cell.textView.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

`@IBAction` function:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonDidPress(_ sender: Any) {
    print(self.email) // returns nil
}
```

Comment: How did you declare the property `email`(self.email) ?

Comment: @YunCHEN `var email = ""` in `ViewController`

Comment: Are you really editing the cell's `textField`?

Comment: @ZonilyJame Yes, I am.

Comment: Could you add the `textFieldDidChange` delegate and print the textField's text property from there?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line `self.email = text` and see if it is set again with `nil` value (or anywhere which assigns the value of the `self.email`. I just copied your code and tested, it works properly

Comment: Did `textFieldDidEndEditing` been called?

Comment: @melvyndev  The problem with my `doneButtonDidPress` `IBAction`. I put a breakpoint when pressing on on of the cells and all the value of  the `self.email` is there as expected.

Comment: @lysov something is changing your email property so, put a didSet callback and put a breakpoint there must help you

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put `self.tableView.endEditing(true)` in `@IBAction func doneButtonDidPress(_:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not refreshing the datasource of your tableview, in didendediting. Your tableview datasource will be an array. You need to assign the textfield value to the array at the corresponding index

In `textFieldDidEndEditing`,

```
   var myCell:UITableViewCell

   var indexPath: NSIndexPath

   myCell = (textField.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell)

   indexPath = table_view.indexPathForRowAtPoint(myCell.center)!
```

At this index path row , assign the value of the textfield to your tableview datasource(array)

```
   self.tableview_list.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).setObject(self.email, forKey: "XYZ")
```

And also reload the tableview at that particular index only.

Answer (score 0):

> In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` assign set tag to you `textfield` and set `UITextfieldDelegate` too
>
> **Note** this is an example for tableview having to textfield Name and RollNo

```
var txtName:String = ""
var txtRollNo:String = ""


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let YourCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourTableViewCellIdentifier") as! YourTableViewCell
            

            YourCell.txtField?.text = itemsData as? String
            YourCell.txtField.delegate = self
            YourCell.txtField.tag = (indexPath.section*10)+indexPath.row
             if(indexPath.section == 0){
                switch indexPath.row {
                case 0:
                    YourCell.txtField.placeholder = "Enter Name "
                    if (self.txtName != ""){
                        YourCell.txtField.text = self.txtName
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    YourCell.txtField.placeholder = "Enter Rollno "
                    if (self.txtRollNo != ""){
                        YourCell.txtField.text = self.txtRollNo
                    }
                    break;
                }
             }
    return YourCell
}
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
     print(textField.tag)
     if textField.tag == 0 {
          self.txtName = textField.text
     }else if textField.tag == 1{
          self.txtRollNo = textField.text
     }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
     print(textField.tag)
     if textField.tag == 0 {
          self.txtName = textField.text
     }else if textField.tag == 1{
          self.txtRollNo = textField.text
     }
}

func printValue(){
    print("\(self.txtName)")
    print("\(self.txtRollNo)")
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the case as I have only one cell with a textfield.

Comment: set tag for `cell.textfield.tag = 1` and then change in `textFieldDidEndEditing` 
`if textField.tag == 1{
          self.email = textField.text
}`

Comment: I've tried the tags. I've found the solution, I posted it as the solution.